# Flash Builder taking over file associations on OS X

Tags: eclipse, macos, coldfusion

I am running OS X Snow Leopard with both Flash Builder 4.5 and Eclipse Indigo as separate installs. Flash Builder has completely taken over anything I associate with Eclipse. I do a lot of ColdFusion development. Sometimes I have to open single files from a system directory or over FTP (not in a project basically). 99% of the time I try to do this, **Flash Builder opens instead of Eclipse**.

Additionally, **changing file associations never sticks**. I will select the .cfc / .cfm file, open File Info, change the Open With dropdown to Eclipse (which I have to browse to manually each time and change the "Reccommended Applications" dropdown to "All Applications"), click "Change All", open the file and only sometimes it works. Regardless, **the next file I open will be right back to Flash Builder**.

**Even crazier** is sometimes I will **choose Eclipse from the association dialog**, press "Add", and **Flash Builder shows up as the application I chose**. It's maddening. No matter what I do, Flash Builder takes over.

The only solution I've found is to **drag the entire Flash Builder application folder to the Trash**, open the file I wanted, then (hopefully remember to) take it out of the Trash before I delete it by accident. It's ridiculous.

I've done lots of Googling and haven't found anyone else with this issue, but I imagine there is some config file sitting somewhere which is causing the system to think Eclipse is the same thing as Flash Builder.

Comment: I voted to migrate this question to [su], since this is not really a programming question but actually a "how to use" question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to reinstall ColdFusion Builder now, it should fix the coldfusion file associations. If your using pure eclipse and not coldfusion builder, then I don't believe it has any file associations.

Comment: I'm using a pure Eclipse install, not ColdFusion Builder. Would that make a difference?

Comment: I didnt think pure eclicse did file associations.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Adobe Flash Builder 4.5 on Mac OS X Version 10.7.5. My particular problem was with `.tex` files which were recognized as `MXML files`. In my case I had to remove the `MXML file` association from  Adobe Flash Builder 4.5 settings as follows:

- Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations > File Types
- Select `.mxml` and Click Remove - Select OK and close  Adobe Flash Builder
- Change file associations in Finder with the Command-I -> Change All routine and now the change should stick

What's more when you re-open Adobe Flash Builder  `.mxml` is still there and this does not affect the file associations in Finder (most likely the launch services database is rebuilt).

For other file-types you most likely would have to inspect the given file with Command-I to find out which "File Associations" to remove in Adobe Flash Builder 4.5 settings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doing the full reinstall seems to have fixed it, but definitely not an ideal solution. I have a feeling I will run into this problem again in the future and I will try out this solution first. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Pure eclipse does not have file associations on OSX. use a real OS if you want to associate files with random executables.